# How to shift from /admin to the domain name?

Tags: wordpress

My problem is that I have installed worpress on CPanel. But when I access my site name i.e. www.loophole.ml it shows the index / page. But when I open www.loophole.ml/admin then I shows my website.
How I can make it directly that when I search www.loophole.ml my website appear not the Index/ page.

Comment: It' s look like you don't any index.php file at the root !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to take wordpress out of the admin folder and install it in the parent folder, e.g.

```
public_html <-- Copy files into this folder
 - admin
 - cgi-bin
```

Once the files are in place you will need to alter the database so that the `home_url` and `site_url` are the same (`http://loophole.ml/`). These fields are located in the `wp_options` table.

Comment: But they are both in the same public_html folder.

Comment: You need to take the files out of the admin folder and put them directly in the public_html folder.